# Unzip a file in C# with isolated storage WP7

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm kinda new to WP7 platform, I'm doing something involved with the isolated storage and kinda stuck right now, it's pretty simple, but not for me though. My app requires to download a zip-file and save to processing, I've done the downloading part and I can save it to an isolated storage, I use isolated storage explorer to check the status, and the file is there.

```
void wcMedia_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    filename1 = "book" + bookId + ".zip";
    if (e.Error != null) return;
    var str = e.Result;

    using (var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (myStore.FileExists(filename1)) myStore.DeleteFile(filename1);
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (var isoStorStr = myStore.OpenFile(filename1, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = str.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                isoStorStr.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }


    Debug.WriteLine("done");
}
```

My problem is how to extract the zip file, my zip contains 3 more folders and some mp3 and image files. I've tried 3rd party libraries like: SharpZipLib, dotnetzip but no success. Can someone help me out. Thanks very much.

Comment: The code above works and the problem is elsewhere? If you can narrow down a library and what you've tried we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,ive tried dotnetzip to open it,code follow:   private void MyExtract()
  {
      string zipToUnpack = "C1P3SML.zip";
      string unpackDirectory = "Extracted Files";
      using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
      {
          // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
          // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
          foreach (ZipEntry e in zip1)
          {
            e.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
          }
       }
    }

Comment: That code looks accurate according to the DotNetZip documentation. So the next step would be to identify what is happening wrong.  Are you getting an error?  Is it working but just not as expected?

Comment: That default method gave me a error follow:'IBM437' is not a supported encoding name.Ive try some solution but not succeeded.Can u point me out some solution.thank u so much.

Comment: Don't think this is your fault. Looks like it is stemmed from DotNetZip being compiled with an older version of .Net.  See here: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/14049.  One comment lists a patch that may fix it for 4.0.

Comment: Or if you change libraries instead and hit an error, post it I'll help you get it working.

Comment: Thank so much,finally ive got a solution ,pretty simple with minor ajustment.Thanks you.where is the thank button plz?much appriciated for your help.

Comment: I'll post what I said last below and click the check box next to it to accept it as an answer.  Good luck with your development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is your fault. Looks like it is stemmed from DotNetZip being compiled with an older version of .Net.

See here: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/14049

One comment lists a patch that may fix it for 4.0.  If you change libraries instead and hit an error, post it I'll help you get it working.